# Django python setting initial values dynamically to form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm building a small web service for inventory control. As part of this, I want to populate a detail view for any of the inventory items. This is what I have so far for that:

```py
class Product_Update(forms.Form):
    Product_Code = forms.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        attrs={"placeholder = <ID here> Readonly = True"
    )
    Name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    Description = forms.Textarea(attrs={"Rows": 3})
    price = forms.DecimalField()
    mini = forms.IntegerField()
    Max = forms.IntegerField()
```

How do I pass the form the parameters?

Comment: if you're working with a detail view then you probably want to work with a model form and let django handle 90% of the logic needed to properly populate the form with data from existing "objects"

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) instead:

```
class ProductUpdate(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('product_code', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'mini', 'max')
```

Now you can easily pass a model instance to your form:

```
def some_view(request):
    instance = Product.objects.first()
    form = ProductUpdate(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

If you want to show multiple products in the same form, you will need to use [`modelformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets):

```
from django import forms

ProductFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(Product, form=ProductUpdate, extra=0)
```

Now in your views.py, you can pass a `QuerySet` to your form:

```
def some_view(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    form = ProductFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=queryset)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access the form's data in the view by accessing request.POST

```
def actionView(request, product_id):
   product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
   form = ProductUpdate(request.POST, instance=product_id)
   form.save(commit=False) #Do this if you want to make changes to some value
   form.price = 112233
   updated_form = form.save()
```

Comment: that's not what OP is looking for. that's changing the object being created not what the form is displaying based on an existing DB entry.